# Optimizing a table with a huge text-field

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005, entity-framework

I have a project which generates snapshots of a database, converts it to XML and then stores the XML inside a separate database. Unfortunately, these snapshots are becoming huge files, and are now about 10 megabytes each. Fortunately, I only have to store them for about a month before they can be discarded again but still, a month of snapshots turn out to become real bad for it's performance...
I think there is a way to improve performance a lot. No, not by storing the XML in a separate folder somewhere, because I don't have write access to any location on that server. The XML must stay within the database. But somehow, the field [Content] might be optimized somehow so things will speed up...
I won't need any full-text search options on this field. I will never do any searching based on this field. So perhaps by disabling this field for search instructions or whatever?
The table has no references to other tables, but the structure is fixed. I cannot rename things, or change the field types. So I wonder if optimizations is still possible.
Well, is it?
The structure, as generated by SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Snapshots](
    [Identity] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Header] [varchar](64) NOT NULL,
    [Machine] [varchar](64) NOT NULL,
    [User] [varchar](64) NOT NULL,
    [Timestamp] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Comment] [text] NOT NULL,
    [Content] [text] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_SnapshotLog] 
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Identity] ASC) 
    WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, 
    STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, 
    IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, 
    ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, 
    FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [IX_SnapshotLog_Header] 
    UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([Header] ASC) 
    WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, 
    STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, 
    IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, 
    ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, 
    FILLFACTOR = 90) 
    ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [IX_SnapshotLog_Timestamp] 
    UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([Timestamp] ASC)
    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, 
    STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
    IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
    ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, 
    FILLFACTOR = 90) 
    ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

---

Performance isn't just slow when selecting data from this table but also when selecting or inserting data in one of the other tables in this database! When I delete all records from this table, the whole system is fast. When I start adding snapshots, performance starts to decrease. After about 30 snapshots, performance becomes bad and the risk of connection timeouts increase.
Maybe the problem isn't in the database itself, although it's still slow when used through the management tool. (Fast when Snapshots is empty.) I mainly use ASP.NET 3.5 and the Entity Framework to connect to this database and then read the multiple tables. Maybe some performance can be gained here, although that wouldn't explain why the database is also slow from the management tools and when used through other applications with a direct connection...

Comment: If the changes are not allowed in the structure of the database then it can only be done in querying. Are your queries reading the [Content] field even when it is not necessary?

Comment: I can still change options for the fields, just not the field names or types. With structure, I only mean name, indices and fields...

Comment: Can you verify that performance is slow when you do direct database operations from a command line, e.g. select a specific record by ID? I can think of no reason why a mere 30 records (even with huge data) would cause a performance problem for SQL server. Text data is not stored in the same page with the record in SQL Server, it should have little or no effect on record access speed. It seems very likely that your access method (Entity Framework) is asking for things that it does not need, e.g. using "SELECT *" when it's not needed or getting records it doesn't need.

Comment: Verified. With no records, SQLCMD executes a simple select query on a *different* table within a 10th of a second. When the number of snapshots goes over 30, the same query takes two seconds. (Btw, the hardware isn't very good for this server but resources are limited and it's a project for internal use only so we're not going to invest in better hardware...)

Comment: Hmm... is full text indexing enabled? What about logging - I don't know too much about the details but check this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd425070.aspx  This is tough, I mean it's hard to optimize if you are so constrained, ideally you would use FILESTREAM. Seems odd that for an internal project you have so many limitations.

Comment: I would recommend combining the answers from @amit_g and @David Waters

Comment: HOw often are you writing to this table?

Comment: I will also point out that text as a datatype has been deprecated, you need to start converting them to varchar(max) or nvarchar(max) anyway. Or you won't be able to upgrade to the next version fo SQL Server.

Comment: @HLGEM, An upgrade to a newer version of SQL Server isn't a requirement, though. It is an internal application which will continue to run on some older hardware. (It's a miracle they got Windows 2008 running on it!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole system became a lot faster when I replaced the TEXT datatype with the NVARCHAR(MAX) datatype. HLGEM pointed out to me that the TEXT datatype is outdated, thus troublesome. It's still a question if the datatype of these columns could be replaced this easy with the more modern datatype, though. (Translated: I need to test if the code will work with the altered datatype...)
So, if i would alter the datatype from TEXT to NVARCHAR(MAX), is there anything that would break because of this? Problems that I can expect?
Right now, this seems to solve the problem but I need to do some lobbying before I'm allowed to make this change. So I need to be real sure it won't cause any (unexpected) problems.

Comment: Look at the code that writes to these fields, specifically look in your code base for WRITETEXT and UPDATETEXT. You might also look for READTEXT.

Answer (score 3):

The table is in PRIMARY filegroup. Could you move this table to a different filegroup or even that is constrained? If you can, you should move it to a different filegroup with its own physical file. That should help a lot. [Check out](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1112) how create new filegroup and move the object to a new file group.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't move it to another filegroup, even though it turned out to improve things a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Given your constraints you could try zipping the XML before inserting into the DB as binary. This should significantly reduce the storage cost of this data.

You mention this is bad for performance, how often are you reading from this snapshot table? If this is just stored it should only effect performance when writing. If you are often reading this are you sure the performance issue is with the datastoreage not the parsing of 10MB of XML?

Comment: It's worse. It's not reading data from this database that is slow. Reading ANY table in this database slows down when this snapshot table grows bigger.